# Flashing an image vs copying files

Tags: embedded, fastboot, flashing

I would like to understand how is flashing an image on device or partition is different from copying same set of files to the device?

Comment: Would you mind to add some more details, please? Are you talking about mass storage devices, or embedded control? Some words on the different processes would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is different because being able to copying files does require:

- a partition to be defined on the drive/eMMC/USB key/SD card,
- a file system to have been created/formatted in one partition.

When you flash an image, you flash all of the partitions, file systems, files in the file system that were existing on the drive/eMMC/USB key/SD card the image was created from.

Bottom line, you cannot copy files on a blank drive/eMMC/USB key/SD card, but you can write an image into it.

Comment: An image doesn't necessarily have to be of an entire physical device, it could be of a single partition or flash bank.  But the main idea is about right - an image brings along its detailed organization and internal ordering, while files just get put wherever in the destination the running filesystem code feels is best.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: you are perfectly right, thanks for your comment. I just kept the answer  concise on purpose given the nature of the (perfectly valid/legitimate) question.